# Dream factory URL

Tags: rest, http, https, dreamfactory

I have a url like http://host/api/v2/service in dream factory. I am finding the method to disable the part api/v2 from the url to obtain the final url like http://host/service . Can i do it or it is limited by Dream Factory?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, If you take a look in your .env file you are able to customize the URL. In the .env file look for the line:

> DF_API_ROUTE_PREFIX=customapi

After that run the following

```
php artisan cache:clear 
php artisan config:clear
```

Thanks